# How do I randomly insert nodes into a binary search tree?

Tags: java, insert, binary-search-tree

I'm a student learning about data structures in Java. I'm less than a beginner so please don't criticize my code too hardly :).

I want to randomly insert nodes into a binary search tree, but don't know how to do this if not manually.

I'll paste the Insert() method here and how I was previously inserting. Also I'm getting a compilation error because of the scanner. Any idea why?

```
    {
        // Create node
        Node node = new Node(key, data);

        // Walk down the tree 
        Node parent = null;
        Node child = root;
        while (child != null)
        {
            // Parent goes down
            parent = child;

            // Child goes down
            if (key.compareTo(child.GetKey()) == 0)
                throw new RuntimeException("Duplicate key.");
            else if (key.compareTo(child.GetKey()) < 0)
                child = child.left;
            else
                child = child.right;        
        }

        // Hang new node from parent or make it the root
        node.parent = parent;
        if (parent == null)
            root = node;
        else if (key.compareTo(parent.GetKey()) < 0)
            parent.left = node;
        else
            parent.right = node;
    }




import java.util.Scanner;
class Test
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Tree tree = new Tree();

        // Create keys
        Node n1 = new Node(null, "1");
        Node n2 = new Node(null, "2");
        Node n3 = new Node(null, "3");
        Node n4 = new Node(null, "4");
        Node n5 = new Node(null, "5");
        Node n6 = new Node(null, "6");
        Node n7 = new Node(null, "7");

        // Create Scanner
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner();

        System.out.print("Enter 'sorted' or 'random': ");
        String s = scanner.nextLine();

        if (s == "sorted")
            tree.Insert("1", n1.GetData());
            tree.Insert("2", n2.GetData());
            tree.Insert("3", n3.GetData());
            tree.Insert("4", n4.GetData());
            tree.Insert("5", n5.GetData());
            tree.Insert("6", n6.GetData());
            tree.Insert("7", n7.GetData());

        if (s == "random")
            tree.Insert("5", n5.GetData());
            tree.Insert("2", n2.GetData());
            tree.Insert("1", n1.GetData());
            tree.Insert("3", n3.GetData());
            tree.Insert("6", n6.GetData());
            tree.Insert("7", n7.GetData());
            tree.Insert("4", n4.GetData());

        if (s != "random" && s != "sorted")
            throw new RuntimeException("Invalid input.");
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "randomly insert" - insert the same 7 nodes but in a random order? or generate a bunch of nodes using a  random number generator?

Comment: @Joni yes, insert the same 7 nodes in a random order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a standard library method in the `Collections` class to shuffle a list.  To use it, we must create a List with the data, and then call `Collections.shuffle`:

```
List<String> data = new ArrayList();
for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
    data.add(String.valueOf(i));
}
Collections.shuffle(data);
```

Now you can just insert the data into the tree:

```
for (String item: data) {
    tree.Insert(item, item);
}
```

---

Regarding the compilation error, there is no Scanner constructor that takes no arguments. You probably wanted to pass in the system standard input stream.

```
    // Create Scanner
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Another thing I noticed: you can't compare strings with `==` like in `if (s == "sorted")` you must use the equals method instead: `if (s.equals("sorted"))`

Yet another thing, you need to use brackets `{ }` with if-statements. Otherwise things that you meant to run conditionally will run always.

```
    if (s == "sorted")
        tree.Insert("1", n1.GetData());
        tree.Insert("2", n2.GetData()); // <-- runs no matter what s is
```